# ¿Cómo imprimir únicamente los números impares en forma de pirámide?

Tags: java, array

El programa también deberá de imprimir la suma de los números impares de cada fila de la pirámide.

Ejemplo:

```java
             1            = 1    

          3     5         = 8  (3+5)       

       7     9    11      = 27 (7+9+11)    

   13    15    17    19   = 64 (13+15+17+19)  

21    23    25    27    29   = 125 (21+23+25+27+29)
```

En este ejemplo la pirámide tiene solamente números impares, sin embargo, esto puede variar, por ende, también podría tener números pares.

Hasta el momento tengo un código que detecta si el elemento de un vector/arreglo es impar y si es la condición es `true`, lo imprime por pantalla:

```java
class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        int suma = 0;
        int[] nums = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29};
        for(int i = 0; i != nums.length; ++i)
        {
            if(nums[i] % 2 != 0)
            {
                suma += nums[i];
                System.out.println(nums[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("La suma de los numeros impares es: "+ suma);
    }
}
```

Al final dice la suma total de los números impares.

**La pregunta del millón:** ¿Cómo podría imprimir los números impares en forma de pirámide y la suma entre ellos?

**Nota:** Los datos de la pirámide deben estar si o si en un vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo podría imprimir los números impares en forma de pirámide y la suma entre ellos?

Para lograr sumar los impares necesitamos saber el índice/posición inicial y máximo (final) de cada fila de la pirámide.

**Por ejemplo**, estos podrían ser los índices iniciales:

```java
             1     <- i = 0    

          3        <- i = 1 

       7           <- i = 3

   13              <- i = 6

21                 <- i = 10
```

Entonces la variable `i` representa el índice inicial de cada elemento de la pirámide (`{1, 3, 7, 13, 21}`).

Sin embargo, necesitamos saber cual es el índice final de `X` fila de la pirámide.

Los índices finales serían:

```java
           Indice:           Inicial   Final
             1               (i = 0,   n = 1)

          3     5            (i = 1,   n = 3)

       7     9    11         (i = 3,   n = 6)

   13    15    17    19      (i = 6,   n = 10)

21    23    25    27    29   (i = 10,  n = 15)
```

**¿Para que me sirve saber estos índices?**

Nos sirve para poder recorrer cada fila de la pirámide y de este modo podremos saber cuales son los números pares o impares. Una analogía sería una matriz de enteros, cada fila tiene `X` elementos, en la cual, podríamos sacar la suma de todos los números pares. Esto es parecido a una pirámide de elementos. La diferencia es que en una matriz el índice final siempre es constante (el tamaño de la columna es la misma para cada fila) y en una pirámide de elementos varía.

La pregunta del millón: **¿Cómo rayos obtengo el índice final de cada fila?**

Con esta simple fórmula:

```java
N = row + i;
```

Donde:

- `N` es el índice final.
- `row` es el número de la fila.
- `i` es el índice inicial.

Comencemos a evaluar algunas filas:

- En la 1era fila `i = 0` y `row = 1`, al momento de reemplazar en la fórmula nos da como resultado: `N = 1 + 0 = 1`.
- En la 2do fila `i = 1` y `row = 2`, al reemplazar nos da: `N = 2 + 1 = 3`.
- En la 3era `i = 3` y `row = 3`, al reemplazar, `N = 3 + 3 = 6`.

Y así sucesivamente vamos reemplazando las valores en cada fila.

Con esto ya tenemos el problema resuelto. Ahora comencemos a modelar nuestras clases.

La primera clase que tendremos será `PyramidRow`. En esta clase tendremos los atributos necesarios para poder almacenar el índice inicial y final de `X` fila.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
class PyramidRow
{
    private int begin; //índice inicial
    private int max;//índice final

    public PyramidRow(int begin, int max)
    {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int getBegin()
    {
        return begin;
    }

    public void setBegin(int begin)
    {
        this.begin = begin;
    }

    public int getMax()
    {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max)
    {
        this.max = max;
    }
}
```

Luego, crearemos otra clase llamada `PyramidRowList` en la cual nos servirá para crear una lista de objetos de tipo `PyramidRow`. De esta forma tendremos la información (índice inicial y final) de cada fila en una lista.

```java
class PyramidRowList
{
    private List<PyramidRow> listRows;

    public PyramidRowList()
    {
        listRows = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<PyramidRow> getListRows()
    {
        return listRows;
    }

    public void setListRows(List<PyramidRow> listRows)
    {
        this.listRows = listRows;
    }
    //El parámetro length es para guardar el tamaño del vector
    public void calculateRow(int length)
    {
        int i = 0, n, row = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            n = row + i;
            if(n > length)
                break;
            listRows.add(new PyramidRow(i, n));
            for(; i < n; i++){}
            row++;
        }
    }
}
```

En el método `calculateRow` es donde vamos a calcular el índice inicial y final de cada fila de la pirámide y luego lo guardaremos como un objeto en la lista.

Por último, solo nos faltaría recorrer la lista de objetos y tener acceso al índice inicial y final de cada fila:

```java
public class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        int impares = 0;
        int lengthPyramid;
        int[] nums = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29};
        //Creamos el objeto
        PyramidRowList listRows = new PyramidRowList();
        //Calculamos los índice iniciales y finales de cada fila
        listRows.calculateRow(nums.length);
        //Almacenamos la cantidad de filas que tenga la piramide
        lengthPyramid = listRows.getListRows().size();
        //Recorremos la lista
        for(PyramidRow row : listRows.getListRows())
        {
            for(int i = lengthPyramid - 1; i != 0; i--)
                System.out.print("\t");
            for(int i = row.getBegin(); i < row.getMax(); i++)
            {
                System.out.print(nums[i] + "\t\t");
                if(nums[i] % 2 != 0)
                    impares += nums[i];
            }
            System.out.print("= "+ impares);
            System.out.println("");
            lengthPyramid--;
            impares = 0;
        }
    }
}


class Program 
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        int suma = 0;
        int[] nums = new int[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29};
        for(int i = 0; i != nums.length; ++i)
        {
            if(nums[i] % 2 != 0)
            {
                suma += nums[i];
                System.out.println(nums[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("La suma de los numeros impares es: "+ suma);
    }
}
```

Y listo, por pantalla nos debería dar esto:
[image: img1]